# Is that possible to delay content load when using asp.net update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, asp.net-4.5

Alright i will try to explain my question as much as possible.

Here an asp.net update panel full page postback

[image]

As you can see it took 215 ms to complete.

However i want new content to be updated only when total 400 ms time passed. Is this possible ? So the request will be completed however it will wait 185 ms more to display postback result.

Thank you

There must be some javascript function etc that replaces current content of update panel once it is done. Now this is the tricky part.

Once postback started i need to start a time. After postback finished i need to check how much time passed. If it reached my threshold i should let javascript to replace inside of update panel. However if the timer is not reached the threshold yet, it should wait until timer reaches threshold then allow new content updating inside update panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer on your update panel to achieve this

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delay-Load-Lazy-Load-UpdatePanel-using-Timer-Control-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: thanks i checked your answer but maybe i didn't quite explain. As you can know there is no certain time when will postback completed. However i want to set a certain threshold. For example 400 ms. So if postback get completed before 400 ms, it will wait total time 400 ms before updating update panel. If it gets completed more than 400 ms there is no problem.